# Mocking a WebClient post when there's a request body

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, webclient

There are several questions with helpful answers about mocking a WebClient object. But I still have problems when doing a post with a body. I'm just using **Mockito** not **mockwebserver**.

This is the method I'm testing:

```
public class RestClient extends BaseRestClient {
 ...
 public <T,G> Mono<T> post(String url, G req, Class<T> resp) throws IOException {
        Mono<T> response = null;

        response = this.getWebClient().post()
                    .uri(url)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,JSON_CONTENT_TYPE)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    //.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(req))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + token)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(resp).log();

        return response.map(resp::cast);
    }
 ...
```

Notice the commented out body line.

And this is the test which works fine with the code above- again notice the commented out line in the test:

```
@Mock
WebClient webClient;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;

@Mock
WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec;

@Mock
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

@InjectMocks
RestClient restClient;

@Test
    public void postTest() throws IOException {
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.accept(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>notNull()))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("resp"));

        //when(requestBodySpec.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);

        restClient.post("http://sampleurl",Object.class, Object.class);
    }
```

Again, everything works fine. But if I put the commented out line back in the code, meaning there's a body to this post, and mock the body by putting the commented out line back in the test, then I'll get **NullPointerException** on **.retrieve()** in the code. Just like I'm missing an object to mock.

I even mocked .retrieve() for **requestHeadersSpec** and **requestBodyUriSpec**:

```
when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
```

And still no success. Any ideas what's wrong there?

Comment: its horrible to mock the ```webclient``` completely but its the only way

Comment: yeah, can't agree more :)

Comment: At times the issue can be importing `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of  `org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I missed mocking the "header" method of requestHeadersSpec:

```
when(requestHeadersSpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
```

So, this works fine now:

```
@Test
    public void postTest() throws IOException {
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);

        when(requestHeadersSpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);

        when(requestBodySpec.accept(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>notNull()))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("resp"));

        Assert.assertNotNull(restClient.post("http://sampleurl",Object.class, Object.class));
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting NullPointerException, suspecting  this line `  `when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);` not returning a mock, but I am doing same in my code.

Comment: It should be returned back if you have the mocked object requestBodySpec defined.

Comment: I am getting NPE at accept() method.

Comment: Make sure requestBodySpec object is mocked and exists.

Comment: @Rookie007 The NPE on accept may be because you are passing a Function<UriBuilder,URI> to the uri() method. There are 5 different method definitions defined in the UriSpec interface:
 S uri(URI uri);
 S uri(String uri, Object... uriVariables);
 S uri(String uri, Map<String, ?> uriVariables);
 S uri(String uri, Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction);
 S uri(Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction);
 
The above question is using the uri(URI uri) method so passing any() is sufficient but if you are using one of the other methods you will need to pass the corresponding argument.

Comment: my code is trying to fetch data from URL even after mocking

Comment: Should be a missing mocked object/method. Again, mocking requestBodySpec seems to be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

After adding headers in my WebClient code It starts to work like a magic

```
    @Test
    public void postMethod() {
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
        when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        when(requestBodyMock.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);

        when(requestHeadersMock.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);

        when(requestBodyMock.accept(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        when(requestBodyMock.contentType(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
        when(requestBodyMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
        when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("output"));
    
        //WebClient call
        TestResponse test = service.testMethod(mockObject);
        assertEquals(test.Status(), 200);
    }
```

Comment: Cool! yeah, adding the header helped me too. that's why I marked the answer above as accepted.

Comment: WHere is responseMock mock coming from?

Comment: You can add it to your test class like. @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriMock;

Comment: The configure it like...   when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock); when(requestBodyUriMock.uri('/uri')).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a `new RestClient()` if you are using `@InjectMocks`.
Also Since you are mocking `WebClient` you do not need to mock  `WebClient.`*` .

So the code becomes

```
@Mock
WebClient webClient;

@InjectMocks
RestClient restClient;

@Test
    public void postTest() throws IOException {
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.accept(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>notNull()))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("resp"));

        //when(requestBodySpec.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);

        restClient.post("http://sampleurl",Object.class, Object.class);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly had restClient instantiated. Thanks for pointing out! Don't think that's why it didn't work though. Should fix it in the question not to confuse more people :) But, where are those WebClient.* objects coming from in your code snippet if you don't have them mocked?

Comment: since you have mocked the WebClient all the methods inside the WebClient can be mocked without having to explicitly mocking them. Also did the suggestion work in your case

Comment: But you still have them all in your code snippet. Like "when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);" which has "requestBodyUriSpec". Where is this object coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking webclient post method with request-body

Example: -

```html
List<ParamountRxPriceResponse> paramountRxPriceResponse = paramountRxWebClient.post()
                    .uri(paramountRxuri.toString()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(paramountRxPriceRequest).retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ParamountRxPriceResponse>>() {
                    }).block();
```

Test Case with mocked.

```
@Test
public void testSbuildBaseBPricingFormat() {


    when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
    when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
    when(requestBodyMock.contentType(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
    when(requestBodyMock.accept(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
    when(requestBodyMock.bodyValue(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
    when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    when(responseMock.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ParamountRxPriceResponse>>>any())).thenReturn(Mono.just(getParamountRxPriceResponse()));
    CompletableFuture<PricingResponse> actulaResultResponse = paramountRxResponseBuilderService
            .buildBasePricingFormat(webClientMock,ProductInfoRequest.builder().formulationId("32332332332").quantity("10").zipCode("423894").build() ,"https://testUri.com","2323321");
    assertNotNull(actulaResultResponse);

}
```