# Unable to Mock Spring WebClient Call

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, webclient, spring-webclient

Unable to make Mock calls work while using webclient, I have seen posts where mocking was working with headers as well but in my case at headers it is failing, requesting review and thank you for your time.

```
   public Mono<ClientResponse> create(Room room, String authorizationToken) {
            CreateRoomRequest createRoomRequest = new CreateRoomRequest();
            createRoomRequest.setroom(room);
            return rnWebclient.post().uri(roomCreateUri)
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationToken)//line 72
                        .body(Mono.just(createRoomRequest), CreateRoomRequest.class).exchange();
            }
```

While trying to Mock webclient call I am receiving NullpointerException at `.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationToken)`

Here is the unit test:

```
    @InjectMocks
    RoomUtil roomUtil;

    @Mock
    WebClient rnWebclient;

    @Mock
    RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriMock;

    @Mock
    RequestBodySpec requestBodySpecMock;

    @Mock
    RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;

    @Mock
    Mono<ClientResponse> monoClientResponseMock;

@Test
    public void testCreateRoom() {
        String token = "xxx";
        Mockito.when(rnWebclient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
        Mockito.when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
        Mockito.when(requestBodySpecMock.header(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
        Mockito.when(requestBodySpecMock.body(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(Class.class)))
                .thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
        Mockito.when(requestHeadersSpecMock.exchange()).thenReturn(monoClientResponseMock);
        Room room= new Room();
        roomUtil.create(room, token);
    }
```

Using Java 1.8
Spring Dependency 2.2.2.RELEASE used:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.danaher.roomNotification.util.RoomUtil.create(RoomUtil.java:72)
    at com.danaher.roomNotification.RoomUtilTest.testCreate(RoomUtilTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which value is null?

Comment: .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationToken)//line 72 returns null on Mock statement : Mockito.when(requestBodySpecMock.header(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);

Comment: There is no signature for uri which takes a single String. Try mocking uri(String uri, Object... uriVariables) instead.

Comment: I was following this post for help and .uri(URI uri) signature supports String too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901364/mocking-a-webclient-post-when-theres-a-request-body , also I tried using uri(String uri, Object uriVariables) signature but it still returns NullPointerException on line 72